# Reuse result of IF condtion in true or false result expression

Tags: mysql

I have the following nested query:

```
SELECT `messages`.*, 
    IF((select `status` from messages_status 
        where messages_status.message_id = messages.id and user_id = 149) IS NULL, 
        'unread', messages_status.status) as `status`
FROM `messages`
```

What I would like to do, if there is no messages_status.status set (i.e. if it is NULL), it should return 'unread'. However, if it is set, is should return its value.

Currently, it returns an error: `Unknown column 'messages_status.status' in 'field list'`

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to the result of the `if`'s condition in other places.  You could repeat the query:

```
IF((select `status` from messages_status 
        where messages_status.message_id = messages.id and user_id = 149) IS NULL, 
    'unread', 
    (select `status` from messages_status 
        where messages_status.message_id = messages.id and user_id = 149))
    as status
```

But it's probably clearer to use a `join` instead:

```
select  m.*
,       coalesce(ms.status, 'unknown')
from    messages m
left join
        messages_status ms
on      ms.message_id = m.id
        and ms.user_id = 149
```

The `coalesce` function produces the first of its arguments that is not `null`.